# Block header in symfony, twig

Tags: symfony, include, twig

I'm wondering...
If I have a website where I use two headers

- header.homepage.html.twig - **only** used at main page
- header.other.html.twig - used everywhere else

Which one should I put into

```
{% block header %} {% include 'main/header.?.html.twig' %} {% endblock header %}
```

in base.html.twig?

I'm almost sure that I can do whatever I want - in this case put `header.other.html.twig` there, as it is used more times. So I need only include `header.homepage.html.twig` once, in index. **BUT** I always see people around putting the *main* header of the page in base.

So my question is - Including the *main* header in base.html.twig is the best practice or some people do it out of habit?

Comment: If other is used `99%` of the time then you should go with the other one yes. Just override the `block header` at your homepage and include the homepage one

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought, just wanted to make sure ;)